# get 3 or 2 groups. one is optional. from string

Tags: json, regex

My nearly working regex:

```
Name":"([^"(]+)(\(\d*?\))?([^"]*)","Civ":"([^"]+)"
```

get me:

```
1 = a1
2 = (1234)
3 = rome
```

but i want:

```
1 = a1
2 = 1234
3 = rome
```

from this source:

```
start {"settings":{"PlayerData":[{"Name":"a1 (1234)","Civ":"rome","Team":0,"AI":false,"Color":{"r":231,"g":200,"b":5}},
```

one more Examples:

## Examples

### Example 1 source

```
start {"settings":{"PlayerData":[{"Name":"a1 (1234)","Civ":"rome","Team":0,"AI":false,"Color":{"r":231,"g":200,"b":5}},
```

{"Name":"a2 (1533)","Civ":"mace","Team":0,"AI":false,"Color":{"r":160,"g":80,"b":200}},

### Example 1 expected result:

```
1 = a1
2 = 1234
3 = rome
```

### Example 2 source

```
{"Name":"a2","Civ":"mace","Team":0,"AI":false,"Color":{"r":160,"g":80,"b":200}},
```

### Example 2 expected result:

```
1 = a2
2 = 
3 = mace
```

Comment: You have 4 capture groups in your regexp, why are you only expecting 3 results?

Comment: yes i only need 3. your answer below is perfect (allowed to click it in 3minutes SO says)

Comment: Don't try to parse JSON with a regex.  Use an existing library that does it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the capture group inside `\(` and `\)`. To make the whole parenthesis pattern optional, use a non-capturing group.

```
Name":"([^"(]+)(?:\((\d*)\))?([^"]*)","Civ":"([^"]+)"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/9Byh6L/1)

Comment: better then my (now) last development: `Name":"([^"(]+)\(?(\d*)\)?([^"]*)","Civ":"([^"]+)"` my is bid shorter but capture more groups

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. This will create 3 capturing groups.

```
\bName":"([^(]*)\(?([^)]*)?\)?","Civ":"([^"]*)"
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/wCu2Y2/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
\bName":"    ##Matching Name: making sure its not a partial match.
([^(]*)      ##Creating 1st capturing group to get everything just before ( here.
\(?          ##Matching ( optional here.
([^)]*)?     ##Creating 2nd capturing group which has everything before ).
\)?","Civ":" ##Matching )(optional)","Civ":" here.
([^"]*)      ##Creating 3rd capturing group to match everything just before " here.
"            ##Matching " here.
```

Comment: Your regexp doesn't work for the second example. Your `\(...\)` is required, not optional.

Comment: @Barmar, its fixed now to handle both the scenarios.